# I want to show category,subcategory,product and price from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

### I have 2tables.one is category which contains id,cat_name,parent_id.This table contains category and subcategory both. parent_id of category is 0 and subcategory's parent id is id of category . another table is product contains id,pnname,price,pro_id.pro_id is id of subcategory.

### Not giving proper value any of this query

```
  id cat_name parent_id      id  pname  pro_id
  --------------------      --------------------
   1 Electronics  0           1  abc     3
   2 Clothing     0           2  def     4
   2 Clothing     0
   3 Phone        1
   4 Kurti        2

  output:
  category      subcategory    Product 
  --------------------------------------
   Electronics     Phone       abc  
   Clothing        Kurti       def
  select product.pname from product where product.pro_id=(SELECT c1.cat_name, c2.cat_name FROM category c1, category c2 WHERE c1.id = c2.parent_id)

SELECT product.pname, category.cat_name
FROM product
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = product.pro_id
OR category.parent_id =0
 SELECT product.pname, category.cat_name
 FROM product INNER JOIN category ON product.pro_id=(SELECTc1.cat_name,  c2.cat_name FROM category c1, category c2 WHERE c1.id = c2.parent_id)
```

Comment: Could you show some data you have and the data output you want? You could use SQLFiddle.com also.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM category c1
LEFT JOIN category c2
    ON c2.parent_id = c1.id
LEFT JOIN product p
    ON p.pro_id = c2.id;
```

Comment: This query shows the tree association of your tables if you want you can filter it via adding *WHERE*  clause. Add comment if you need more.